# Prove that a set is countable if the sup of the sum of its finite subsets is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be an infinite set of positive real numbers. Define $S := \sup_{B \in \mathcal{B}}\sum_{x\in B}x$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the collection of all finite subsets of $A$. I want to show that $A$ is countable if $S < \infty$.

Since $S < \infty$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite subset $B$ of $A$ such that $S - \epsilon < \sum_{x \in B} x < S$. My ultimate idea is to show that $A_n := A \cap (1/n, \infty)$ is finite and therefore $A = \cup_n A_n$ is countable. But it is not clear to me that the existence of such an finite subset $B$ implies that $A_n$ is finite. Is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could just show directly that $A_n$ is finite by showing that $|A_n|\le nS$?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why this is true?

Comment: You want me to elaborate on why I think that, if I have more than $nS$ numbers, and each of those numbers is bigger than $1/n$, then the sum will be bigger than $S$? Sorry, I can't explain it, it's just a hunch I have. That's why I said "maybe" in my previous comment.

Comment: @bof I just have a quick question. If $A_n$ contains infinitely many elements, then is it okay if their sum is greater than $S$? Your reasoning seems to be based on the assumption that $A_n$ is a finite subset, but isn't this what I'm trying to show there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sum_{x \in A_n} x \leq S$. But $x \in A_n$ implies $x >\frac 1 n$ so $\sum_{x \in A_n} x >\frac  1n Card(A_n)$. So we get $Card (A_n) \leq nS$. In poarticular, $Card (A_n) <\infty$ for each $n$. Since $A =\bigcup A_n$ we are done.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a quick question. Can I use $\sum_{x\in A_n} x \le S$ if I do not know whether $A_n$ is finite or not? Since $S$ is the sup of the sum of elements of finite subsets, the argument seems a bit circular.

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics If $A$ is an infinite set, then for any natural number $k$, there is a subset of $A$ with exactly $k$ elements. (You can prove that by induction on $k$.) In particular, in the case at hand, $A$ has a finite sebset with more than $nS$ elements.

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics If every finite subset of $A_n$ has cardinality at most $nS$ then $A_n$ has to be a finite set with at most $nS$ elements.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see! This answers my question. So the proof technically should with "consider an arbitrary finite subset of $A_n$ ... "?